# Appending Formats to Strings in Java

Tags: java

I have this code in Java, the getter methods return Strings:

```
String stringbuilder="";
stringbuilder = String.format("%d/%d\n", this.getSlotNum(), this.getPortNum());
stringbuilder = stringbuilder+String.format(" " + this.getPortSpeed() +"\n");
stringbuilder = stringbuilder+String.format("%d\n", this.getPortMode());
```

C# has a StringBuilder Class with an AppendFormat() method that lets me append a formatted string directly to the StringBuilder instance without having to do the concatenation.  I don't see an AppendFormat() method in thethn Java StringBuider class. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: You're not actually using StringBuilder in the first place?

Comment: Calling a variable `stringbuilder` doesn't automatically mean you are using a `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: I know I'm not using StringBuilder.  I am converting a C# project to Java.  It was easier to leave the variable named 'stringbuilder' than it was to refactor it.  The Java StringBuilder class doesn't seem to have any methods to do what I want.  With String I at least have a format() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://java.dzone.com/tips/better-stringbuilder) looks like the Java [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class is what you want:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
formatter.format("Hello, world\n");
if (name != null) {
    formatter.format("My name is %s\n", name);
} else {
    formatter.format("Please email me at %s\n", email);
}
doUse(formatter.toString();
```